# Codeigniter pass form value as url segment

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have an issue with codeigniter. I want to pass a form value (from a dropdown) as URL segment in the next page. However I have searched high and low but could not find the solution.

Here is my view:

```
<?= form_open('admin_gallery_upload/upload_images/'); ?>
<?= form_label('Gallerij', 'gallery_id'); ?><br/>           
<?= form_dropdown('gallery_id', $select_dropdown); ?>
<?= form_submit('submit', 'Volgende',  'class="submit"'); ?>
<?= form_close(); ?>
```

My controller:

```
function upload_images() {
   $gallery_id = $this->input->post("gallery_id");
   echo $gallery_id;        
}
```

So instead of echoing the `$gallery_id` as done in the controller, it should become the third url segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and put select box id as `gallery_id`:

```
function redirectFunction(){
    var val  = document.getElementById("gallery_id").value;
    alert(val); //see if alerts the correct value that is selected from the dropdown
    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url()?>admin_gallery_upload/upload_images/'+val;
}
```

Change the following lines, to add the id of the dropdown as I said,

```
$js = 'id="gallery_id" onChange="redirectFunction();"';
form_dropdown('gallery_id', $select_dropdown,'',$js);
```

Comment: That does not appear to do anything

Comment: I already added that, as you requested, but that did not work

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: I am no longer receiving any errors, but for some reason nothing happens either

Comment: Correction; it does! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in form open function extra parameter by default it is post see below code :-

```
<? $arr = array('method'=> 'GET');?>
<?= form_open('admin_gallery_upload/upload_images/',$arr); ?>
```

And get on controller using :-

```
$this->input->get();
```

Comment: Is there no direct way of passing the gallery_id? Since I have no idea how to only pass the id instead of all form information

Comment: Then You have to pass in to simple javascript function galler_id and redirect it.